# Python, how to pass reference to list of list (not value)

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

I want to pass a refference to a list of lists of ints, NOT the int value itself.

I have a list of list of ints, which represents a root-first binary tree, which I am calling `aTriangle` 
I am building a list called  `path` as I am walking down `aTriangle` 
 `path` is being filled with references to `aTriangle` of the format `aTriangle[i][j]`
the problem is that when I try to print or pass `path`, it is a list of int values, NOT a list of the references that I put in it.

For example,

```
test_triangle = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
test_list = [test_triangle[0][0], test_triangle[1][0]]
print(test_list)
```

prints out `[1, 2]` (similarly, passing test_list passes on the values)

but I want  `[test_triangle[0][0], test_triangle[1][0]]`

How do I build a list of references that STAY as references? Or if this is infeasible, if there another method for me to keep tract of both indexes associated with the value, since these index values are important to later steps.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how python lists work, when you index a list of lists what you get is in fact a reference to the contained list.. But when you print it python is smart enough to print the repr of the referenced list rather that the address of the list as would be the case in c/c++

Comment: **is there another method for me to keep tract of both indexes associated with the value** yes store the indices in `test_list`.

Comment: "is there another method for me to keep tract of both indexes associated with the value" .. Look up xarray, elements contained in an xarray store the index that they are contained in.

Comment: Python always has reference semantics (although it is neither call by value **nor** call by reference)

Comment: @Countout-Integral you know what, this is perfect. it's simple, straight forward way to keep tract of my indexes, and when I do eventually need the value I can easily call it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

**Disclaimer** -> This is pure hack, I would suggest to look for more sophisticated python module/library.

```
test_triangle = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
test_list = (test_triangle[0][0], test_triangle[1][0])

values_and_indexes = {}

for index, value in enumerate(test_triangle):
    for _i, _v in enumerate(value):
        values_and_indexes[f"test_triangle[{index}][{_i}]"] = _v

print(values_and_indexes)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'test_triangle[0][0]': 1, 'test_triangle[1][0]': 2, 'test_triangle[1][1]': 3, 'test_triangle[2][0]': 4, 'test_triangle[2][1]': 5, 'test_triangle[2][2]': 6}
```